# How can I find out why this Rust program to echo lines from stdin is slow?

Tags: performance, io, rust

Given the following Rust program:

```
fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    for line in reader.lock().lines() {
        match line {
            Ok(l) => print!("{}", l),
            Err(_) => continue,
        }
    }
}
```

`yes | program` achieves 1.04MiB/s throughput, according to `pv`. The trivial C program below, which I fully realize does less, gives me a throughput of 141MiB/s.

```
int main() {
    int c;
    while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

How do I go about finding out what's keeping the Rust version from being faster? While I would appreciate if you just told me what to change to make it faster, I'm far more interested in how to find out what needs to be changed.

Edit: I tried changing `lines()` to `chars()` in the Rust version, to approximate the C version better, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisations? `cargo build --release` or `rustc -O file.rs`

Additionally, if you want to find more information about the assembly produced, you can pass `--emit asm` to rustc

Comment: I was not, as a matter of fact. I did try just now, and the difference in throughput is decent, even if nowhere near what I'd expect (1.04MiB/s to 2.97MiB/s). I'm not familiar with assembly, so I'm not sure whether inspecting it would be useful.

Comment: These programs seem fairly different, lines and char yield decoded unicode data, and print! goes through type-conversion and encoding. The C program blindly copies bytes from the input to the output.

Comment: Is there a way I can speed up the process, perhaps by skipping unnecessary steps?

Comment: @mkaito: Are you sure the C program is running at 141MiB/s? I'm getting 1.7MiB/s for Rust (with `--opt-level=3`) and 10.9MiB/s for C (with `-O3`). FWIW, `cat` and `tee` are running at 30MiB/s for me on the same system.

Comment: I only get 6MB/s with your C program (`yes | ./prog | pv > /dev/null`) so the 141MB/s seems dodgy (cat gives me 18). Using opt 3 I get 1MB/s with your rust, 1.3 using `while let Ok(c) = reader.read_byte() { writer.write_u8(c) }`, 1.8 calling `read_byte` on `StdinReaderGuard` (and removing an implicit `lock()` call for every `read_byte`), and 2MB/s by getting the guard's underlying `BufferedReader` with `deref_mut()`. That's about my limit on this so far, the code is kinda crappy and the assembly is full of garbage.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP is not interested in any and all improvements of the code and does not really want a code review, but wants their problem fixed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, because it seems to be about how to make something work, rather than code review

Comment: The code works just fine, but it's surprisingly slow. I state specifically in my question that I want to learn how to approach problems like these rather than someone to just paste me a faster version.

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to treat this as a code review question where the goal is to figure out how to write high-performance I/O code in Rust.

There are two critical steps to speed up Rust I/O:

1. Make sure the optimizer is turned on. Rust loops have terrible performance in debug mode. Turning the optimizer on should probably get you near 25 MB/sec or so, at least in my experience.
2. Avoid line-based I/O, or anything else which uses `String` values. For maximum performance, we want to work with raw byte buffers and avoid ever letting Rust call `malloc` or `free`.

Here's some code which drills down to `fill_buf`, which is about as low as we can go before losing generality:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::{IoError, IoErrorKind};

fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let mut buffer = reader.lock();
    let mut writer = io::stdout();
    loop {
        let consumed = match buffer.fill_buf() {
            Ok(bytes) => { writer.write(bytes).unwrap(); bytes.len() },
            Err(IoError{kind: IoErrorKind::EndOfFile, ..}) => break,
            Err(ref err) => panic!("Failed with: {}", err)
        };
        buffer.consume(consumed);
    }
}
```

Of course, this means that you need to find the line breaks yourself, and be prepared for lines to be split over multiple buffers. Also, notice how I pass `bytes.len()` outside of the `match` block before trying to call `buffer.consume()`. This is necessary to placate the lifetime checker.

Trying this with `pv`:

```
cat /dev/zero | target/release/throughput | pv > /dev/null
```

…gives us a throughput of **527 MB/s**.

Comment: What is the issue the lifetime checker has with calling consume() inside the match branch?

Comment: Try it. :-) Basically, the `bytes` value returned by `fill_buf` points to an internal buffer inside `buffer`, and that prevents anybody from calling `&mut self` methods on `buffer` until `bytes` goes out of scope. So we need to do all our work inside the `match` block, then escape so that `bytes` goes away and we can safely access `buffer` again. There's some tricky Rust magic in these low-level APIs.

Comment: Wow, and I thought C pointers were hard to grok :D this lifetimes business is going to take some work to comprehend.

Comment: Well, to be fair, if you were using this API in C, you'd need to be very careful to avoid clobbering the buffer before you were done using it. If I'm going to have to say, "Well, this pointer is still valid _here_, because I haven't yet called _that_," I don't mind the compiler checking these things automatically. But yeah, `fill_buf` is a weird, low-level API with tricky lifetimes.

Comment: And as far as I've learned so far, the only way to get good throughput in this kind of application. Although the blind pass-through makes for a complicated filter application. For example, while your code is really fast and I think I understand what's going on, I have a hard time working out how to get my filter on it. Namely, I want to drop anything that's not valid unicode.

Comment: I actually have some [half-baked code](https://github.com/emk/rust-streaming) that can do line-based I/O at >250GB/sec, but it can't use regular Rust iterators yet. Basically, it just chops up the data returned by `fill_buf` into lines, but if a line is broken across two buffers, it uses a temporary internal buffer. But this code isn't really easy to reuse until we get support for types of the form `T<'a>`, passing lifetimes to type parameters.

Answer (score 6):

> How do I go about finding out what's keeping the Rust version from being faster?

In the general case you would use a profiler like Linux's `perf` tool to give you a rundown of which functions are eating up all your time. But `perf` is broken on my computer at the moment and I don't feel like fixing it, so let's try some more Rust-specific advice. :)

The first thing to do is note that `print!` is a macro (note the exclamation point!), which means that it's expanding at compile-time to do... something. We can figure out what that something is by passing `--pretty expanded` to the compiler, yielding this:

```
#![feature(phase)]
#![no_std]
#![feature(globs)]
#[phase(plugin, link)]
extern crate "std" as std;
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::*;
fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    for line in reader.lock().lines() {
        match line {
            Ok(l) =>
            match (&l,) {
                (__arg0,) => {
                    #[inline]
                    #[allow(dead_code)]
                    static __STATIC_FMTSTR: &'static [&'static str] = &[""];
                    ::std::io::stdio::print_args(&::std::fmt::Arguments::new(__STATIC_FMTSTR,
                                                                             &[::std::fmt::argument(::std::fmt::Show::fmt,
                                                                                                    __arg0)]))
                }
            },
            Err(_) => continue ,
        }
    }
}
```

Yikes... that's a whole lot of stuff just for printing a line via a type-safe format string. In truth we really don't care about type-safe format strings in this application, given that we want an apples-to-apples comparison to C, so we can get rid of the macro entirely... but what to replace it with? I could give you the step-by-step, but instead I'll point you to the stdio docs and let you poke around at your leisure: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/stdio/

Here's the result of me perusing the docs there:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let mut writer = io::stdout();

    while let Ok(c) = reader.read_u8() {
        writer.write_u8(c);
    }
}
```

This looks much more directly comparable to your C program.

(If you're wondering what `while let foo` does, it is simply treated as an infinite loop that breaks whenever you get an enum that isn't `foo`. In this case, `reader.read_u8()` returns an `IoResult`, and will give you the `Ok` variant when it gets a char or the `Err` variant when it hits EOF. See `read_u8`'s documentation here: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Reader.html#method.read_u8)

I'm sure this program could be optimized further, perhaps by investigating the `stdin_raw()` and `stdout_raw()` functions mentioned in the stdio docs. But this should give you a good starting point, and give you the tools to dig deeper yourself.

EDIT: Changed `read_char` to `read_u8` for better analogy with C.

Comment: Brilliant reply! I actually learned a lot. Sadly, the code you arrive at has exactly the same throughput as my code, but I can't seem to figure out why. `perf` says the top symbol is something from the kernel called `_raw_spin_lock`, which doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: It's a shame stdin_raw is private.